# Cannot receive multiple fomData in express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-dropzone

We are always very grateful for your help.
I am using react 18.2.0 and express 4.17.1 to create an image uploader.

I implemented the following code and uploaded 2 images (aaa.jpg, bbb.jpg) from the front end side, but the express side only receives aaa.jpg.

I don't know what is wrong, so if anyone can help me, I would appreciate it if you could tell me what is wrong.

Thank you in advance.

## frontend(react)

### upload.jsx

```js
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone'
import axios from 'axios'

const MediaLibrary = () => {

  const onDrop = async (acceptedFiles) => {

    const formData = new FormData()
    
    acceptedFiles.forEach((file) => formData.append('files', file, file.name))

    try {

      const { data } = await axios.post(`/upload-image-file`, formData)

      console.log(data)

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }

  }

  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({ onDrop })

  return (<>

    <div {...getRootProps()}>
    
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
      
      {isDragActive ? <p>Drop the files here ...</p> : <p>Drag 'n' drop some
        files here, or click to select files</p>}
        
    </div>

  </>)

}

export default MediaLibrary
```

#backend(express)

### routers/upload.js

```js
import express from 'express'
import formidable from 'express-formidable'

const router = express.Router()

// controllers
import { uploadImageFile} from '../controllers/upload'

router.post('/upload-image-file', formidable(), uploadImageFile)

export default router
```

### controllers/upload.js

```js
export const uploadImageFile = async (req, res) => {
  try {

    console.log('req.files ===>', req.files)
    
    return

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

## upload files

```
aaa.jpg
bbb.jpg
```

## result

```json
 files: {
    files: File {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      size: 534052,
      path: '/var/folders/7h/wgg4krmj5gz6vtj42s1wzx6c0000gq/T/upload_d7c597a4f6a3eea2e6d6c5748103f22f',
      name: 'aaa.jpg',
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      hash: null,
      lastModifiedDate: 2022-11-12T00:55:08.788Z,
      _writeStream: [WriteStream],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  },
```